# Queria saber como eu poderia mudar a cor do botão quando passo o mouse por cima

Tags: html, css, button

Nesse código eu consegui colocar um `background-color: #212b36;` pelo html
mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que o botão mude de cor quando passo o mouse por cima.
parece que ele sempre prioriza a cor que eu defini no style="" no html (até porque se eu tiro a cor que eu defini, o meu :hover funciona normalmente)

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg mt-5" role="group">
        <button id="enviar" type="button" class="btn rounded-5 fw-bold" style="height: 53px; width: 183px; background-color: 212b36; color: white;">enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é você não usar o css inline(no código HTML), até porque ele tem prioridade sobre o interno e externo.
Tenta aplicar esses estilos num CSS interno ou externo como te falei e depois você que você atribuir o background-color ao botão, cria outro seletor com :hover e atribui o background-color que você quer. Isso deve resolver seu problema e mudar a cor do botão quando passar o mouse por cima dele.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que vc esteja se referindo ao onmousemove...
É um evento DOM que ativa uma function onde vc pode fazer um bloco que altere as características do seu botão no momento em que passar o mouse por cima,
esse recurso resolve o seu problema, mas é no Javascript. Na documentação vc consegue ver a sintaxe, e é bem fácil de usar.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousemove